# Is it safe to restore ReportServer database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2017

I need to upgrade and migrate from SSRS 2012 to 2017. Database backup/restore seems work. But database objects on 2012 ReportServer database different in structure from ReportServer from 2012. When I went through in place upgrade on SQL Server 2012 there was a warning:

> migrate your reports first/ SSRS 2012 will be uninstalled...

But when I use PowerShell migration scripts and `rs.exe`, I can't migrate Users / Security setting nor DataSource passwords.

Can someone confirm that backup/restore is a safe way Upgrading from SSRS 2012 to SSRS 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Schema of the database restored from sql 2012 gets upgraded when SSRS configuration have the database selected as repository. looks like I overcomplicated the task. Using backup/restore for the upgrade and migration works. I wish someone who went through similar task could confirm that it does not cause problems on the long run. Thank You.